# How do I build a Recurly.js form with div elements?

Tags: javascript, forms, recurly

My team is using Recurly.js to build a payments page into our website. We've been following the docs from https://docs.recurly.com/js. According to the docs,

> Build a form however you like. Use the data-recurly attribute to identify input field targets to Recurly.js. To identify where Recurly.js will inject card data fields, we recommend using simple div elements.

The problem is that the `div` elements don't actually show in the form. Here's a short reproducible example based off of the docs:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <!-- Recurly.js script and API key config -->
  <script src="https://js.recurly.com/v4/recurly.js"></script>
  <script>recurly.configure('... API Key here...');</script>
</head>
<body>

  <form>
    <input type="text" data-recurly="first_name">
    <input type="text" data-recurly="last_name">
    <div data-recurly="number"></div>
    <div data-recurly="month"></div>
    <div data-recurly="year"></div>
    <div data-recurly="cvv"></div>
    <input type="hidden" name="recurly-token" data-recurly="token">
    <button>submit</button>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is what it looks like:

[image: Recurly.js form example]

As you can see, the two `input`s show fine, but none of the `div`s show correctly.

**What are we doing wrong and how do we build a Recurly.js form with `div` elements?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The javascript code that calls configure cannot be in the head tag and should be located in the body tag

```
<script>recurly.configure('... API Key here...');</script>
```

This example should show you how to set it up properly.  Notice where they put the javascript in the body: https://github.com/recurly/recurly-js-examples/blob/master/public/minimal/index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <!-- Recurly.js script and API key config -->
  <script src="https://js.recurly.com/v4/recurly.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
    <input type="text" data-recurly="first_name">
    <input type="text" data-recurly="last_name">
    <div data-recurly="number"></div>
    <div data-recurly="month"></div>
    <div data-recurly="year"></div>
    <div data-recurly="cvv"></div>
    <input type="hidden" name="recurly-token" data-recurly="token">
    <button>submit</button>
  </form>
  <script>recurly.configure('... API Key here...');</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The browser loads javascript in the head, which loads up recurly, and then in the body you can use recurly.